# Stolen Iphone 6s and yet its off

Tags: iphone

My iphone was stolen yesterday, and yet it appears turned off and offline. I got into icloud to find my iphone but nothing. Someone told me that I had to turn on find my device in my device so I can find it in case its lost. Could I ever locate this phone as it is right now, with the find my device off?

Comment: Do you mean that you never enabled Find my iPhone, from the phone itself, before it was lost? https://support.apple.com/HT205362

Comment: Yes I never enabled it.

Comment: Then you have no way to locate it.

Answer (score 2):

If someone turns it on, the phone will connect to data automatically. Then you can see it on icloud.

Answer (score 1):

iPhones connect to cellular automatically when they are powered on.